# SonarQube - connecting to URL anonymously?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have SonarLint plugin 3.4.0 installed in STS 3.8.1 - I am trying to connect to a URL for SonarQube which I can connect to fine through a browser(Access is provided to anyone).  Is there anyway to do this through the Eclipse plugin?  It's asking me for a token or user/password which I do not have and just want to connect to it anonymously as I do via a web browser.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a token to access to the SonarQube server, even if project is public.
To do that, you need to create a token from your user page : My Account -> Security -> Generate Tokens.